# animateTransform moves an object despite beginning and end values being the same

Tags: svg

I keep some text (Click to rerun) below the SVG bounding area until an animation ends. I then use animateTransform to move the text up to the middle of the screen. When the user clicks I use another animateTransform to move the text back below the screen until the animation ends. Below are the two animateTransforms. Note that the start and end values of clickAniHide are both 0,0, yet this moves the text off of the screen correctly! If I remove this animateTransform the text does not move. The text object is in the defs tag and is referenced by a  tag. The text object is not within any container that could be moving it.

For simplicity I'm posting just the relevant animateTransforms to start, but I will post more/all of the code if necessary. Thanks!

```
   <animateTransform 
    id="clickAniShow"
    xlink:href="#rerun"
    attributeType="XML"
    attributeName="transform"
    type="translate"
    calcmode="discrete" 
    dur="0.1s"
    begin="boxani2.end+0.75s;"
    keyTimes="0; 1"
    values="0, 0; 0, -350;"
    fill="freeze" 
    />

   <animateTransform 
    id="clickAniHide"
    xlink:href="#rerun"
    attributeType="XML"
    attributeName="transform"
    type="translate"
    calcmode="discrete" 
    dur="0.1s"
    begin="restarter.click+0.2s;"
    keyTimes="0; 1"
    values="0,0; 0,0;"
    fill="freeze" 
    />
```

Comment: BTW, this (and other) animations I've made only run in Chrome. I just get a static image in Firefox and Edge. SVG support seems pretty spotty...unless I'm missing some magic incantations.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the values in an animation replace any previous value the attribute had.

- For your first animation, at 0s, `transform(0,0)` is set, and at 0.1s, `transform(0,-350)` is set and remains there according to the `fill="freeze"` rule.
- For your second animation, at 0s, `transform(0,0)` is set, and at 0.1s, `transform(0,0)` is set again. Remember, before that animation, but after the first it was at`transform(0,-350)`.

There are two additional [rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/animate.html#AdditionAttributes) you can set:

- `additive="sum"`: If your text element had for example a `transform="scale(...)"`  attribute before any animation starts, the animation would not replace that value, but translate the already scaled element.
- `accumulate="sum"`: If an element has multiple animations, one animation starts at the end state of the previous, just like you expected to happen here.

It should be `calcMode`, not `calcmode` by the way.

As for SMIL animation support, Edge and Internet Explorer do not support SMIL animations at all. Starting with IE 10 you can use [CSS animations](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations) instead. I can't immediately spot why you have a problem with Firefox.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I think you've helped me before (and probably will again)! If I have this right my problem was that I was thinking of the values as absolute coordinates, when they are instead values of *transformations*, in this case, translation. So when the second animation set the text to 0, 0 ; 0, 0, it set it back to its original position below the screen, and then "moved" it by 0, 0.